# Sending USSD codes in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create an app with React Native to **sending some USSD codes** and **Manage SMSs**. 
actually, I need to do two operations in my app:

1. USSD
2. SMS

I Googled it but there are not many resources about this topic, so If someone knows how to do it, I'll appreciate a lot your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has a PhoneAuth module, which will send a verification code to the device via SMS.

You can find more info here : https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/auth/phone-auth.md

Also keep in mind that you have to add the Native Firebase module for React Native and not the web based one as it does not support Phone authentication.

Comment: Dear Aswin, As if you did not understand me correctly. I need something to send USSD and a library to manage SMS (Receive and read the message in my case).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [react-native-ussd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ussd) library, for dialing and receiving USSD responses.
But currently only Android is supported.